# how to change the dark mode in react native version 0.73?

Tags: react-native

i setup a new project using react-native version 0.73 but is getting in dark mode instead of light mode in previos version . How to change or disable this feature ? And one more thing when save with control + s it is working fine but when hitting reload button it is sending 404 error in the metro bundler

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.